# How do I use the latest version of jcommander with a Gradle project

Tags: gradle

I have a reasonably uncomplicated build that used to work fine in Maven. When I ported it to Gradle, I can see that jcommander-1.12.jar is being pulled in from a transitive dependency (I think through TestNG). This is overriding my explicit dependency on jcommander 1.35.

JCommander 1.12 does not support some annotations and values that I rely on in 1.35.

I can remove all dependencies on jcommander with something like

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.beust', module: 'jcommander'
}
```

(See http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/gradle-goodness-exclude-transitive.html)

So how do I prioritise my explicit dependency over the inherited one?

**UPDATE**

This is the output of `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency jcommander`

```
$ gradle.bat dependencyInsight --dependency jcommander
:dependencyInsight
com.beust:jcommander:1.35
\--- compile
```

Interestingly it doesn't even list jcommander 1.12 at all...

[Gradle is not honoring resolutionStrategy.force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282893/gradle-is-not-honoring-resolutionstrategy-force) seems to be a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat unexpected behavior. By default, when Gradle detects a conflict, it goes with the *newer* dependency. Trying running `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency jcommander` to get a little more information on why version 1.12 is being chosen.

Regardless, you can always force a particular version of a dependency.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.beust:jcommander:1.35'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is a problem, but I found the root cause.

I was actually porting a command line app to a Gradle plugin, which meant that I added the following lines as dependencies:

```
compile gradleApi()
compile localGroovy()
```

If I replace `compile gradleApi()` with compile `"org.gradle:gradle-core:2.0"`, the correct version of JCommander is resolved.